# Details about “fingerprinting” algorithms for groups?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, algorithms, finite-groups

where can I find details about "Fingerprinting" algorithms (to test whether two groups are non-isomorphic)

> "‘Fingerprinting’: For every group $G_1,…, G_r$ evaluate various
>   isomorphism-invariant properties. Split the list up into several sublists
>   such that every sublist contains the groups with certain properties
>   only."

—Page 405 from *Handbook of Computational Group Theory*

Comment: If you don't want this to be closed, you need to be much more precise about your question. Right now, it's so vague as to be unanswerable.

Comment: Also, I think the answer given on your previous question is adequate. (The algorithms you have found are probably already well-known and inefficient.)

Comment: I vote against closing this question. If you plan to vote to close it, and this counter-vote has not yet been cancelled, please, instead of voting, add a comment noting that you have cancelled my counter-vote.

Comment: I also disagree with close votes.

Answer (score 2):

*Handbook of Computational Group Theory* says "for a more detailed description, consult Hans Ulrich Besche and Bettina Eick, "Construction of Finite Groups", *Journal of Symbolic Computation*, vol.**27** (1999), p.387–404". Have you tried that?

Comment: yes , but it looks like "Fingerprinting" ( as its meaning ) is behind the scenes

Comment: The methods described in that paper were not really designed as general non-isomorphism testing algorithms, they were more of a collection of heuristic tests for handling the very large sets of groups that arose during the generation of the small groups (up to order 2000). With a large number $n$ of groups of the same order, even when testing whether a given pair is isomorphic is quick, you want to avoid having to do $\binom{n}{2}$ of these tests. Hence the quick fingerprinting procedure for splitting the large set into smaller subsets.

Comment: please more information about the topic Professor Holt

Comment: The idea here is this: You have $n$ things, in this case groups, and some of them are identical.  You can easily compare any two to see if they are identical, but to sort them into families of identical things, you would have to compare each object with each other, a total of $(n^2-n)/2 \approx n^2/2$ comparisons. If you could pre-sort the objects into $k$ classes, each of size $n/k$, such that two objects in different classes were *never* identical, you would need only compare objects within each class, a total of approximately $k\cdot (n/k)^2/2 = n^2/2k$ comparisons, only $1/k$ as many.